# Optimize winnings in a money making game.

Tags: probability, optimization

So, given a continuous random variable A (with some density and CDF function), and a value I choose V, what is the equation to determine the best value V to maximize my earnings given that I will be paid V if it is less than A, but if A is less than or equal to V, I get nothing.

Now, my logic suggests that without having some sort of idea what the distribution is I should be betting less than the mean of the random variable function, but I don't know how to generalize without knowing that.

Part two specifically refers to a case where A is an exponential RV, in which case, I believe I should be betting E(X), or $1/\lambda $

Is my reasoning behind part two faulty?  If not, how do I generalize it beyond just saying to bet E(X)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal bet is when $VP(A\geqslant V)$ is maximal. This can have no finite solution $V$, for example if the distribution of $A$ is Cauchy. But if $A$ is integrable, the function $x\mapsto xP(A\geqslant x)$ is $0$ at $0$ and at $+\infty$ and positive inbetween hence the maximum indeed exists. The place(s) $V$ where it (they) occur(s) solve(s) the equation $Vf_A(V)=P(A\geqslant V)$.

If $A$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda$, then $VP(A\geqslant V)=V\mathrm e^{-\lambda V}$ is maximal at $V=1/\lambda$. The fact that $V=E(A)$ is not general.